# Python hash md5 not running

Tags: python, authentication, hash, md5

I want to create a hash md5 code to authenticate in a xml comunnication. Server send me a token and, with this token and a activation code, I need to generate a hash, but it doesnt run as I expect:

```
md5 = hashlib.md5()

md5.update(bytearray('00000160471720180327121801781264'))

codigo =[57,51,50,57,52,52]

cod = bytearray(codigo)

md5.update(cod)

print md5.hexdigest()
```

The result should be `24dd32f9f349801e0d6996693dff7a8c` but I dont get that result...why???

Comment: MD5 is extremely outdated, please do not use it for any new code and please switch any old code over to something newer, like sha256.

Comment: And what result exactly do you get from your code?

Comment: This code does not run because `bytearray('00000160471720180327121801781264') throws a `TypeError: string argument without an encoding`. What encoding does this input use?

Comment: Why do you think you should get `24dd32f9f349801e0d6996693dff7a8c` as a result?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the md5 hash of `00000160471720180327121801781264932944` which is `d6f08df4ca20ae594e07d2a6dae8f978`.

```
md5.update(bytearray('00000160471720180327121801781264'.encode("UTF8")))
codigo = [57, 51, 50, 57, 52, 52]
cod = bytearray(codigo)
md5.update(cod)
```

is equal to do:

```
md5.update(bytearray('00000160471720180327121801781264932944'.encode("UTF8")))
```